# ¿Cómo hago que en una petición mysql con where se ejecute solo en el ultimo registro de dos tablas?

Tags: mysql

Tengo esta petición `mysql`

```
select A.colum1 from   tabla1 as A, tabla2 as B where A.campo1= B.campo2
```

El objetivo es que compare el ultimo registro de los dos campos de las dos tablas, ahora esta comparando pero no el ultimo registro, compara todos los registros del campo de las dos tablas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como nota importante, en las bases de datos relacionales, el orden de las tuplas o registros no importa. Dado que no existe "El primero" o "El ultimo" si que es cierto que podemos ordenar la información en base a sus campos (order by). Una vez dicho esto:

Yo te recomiendo que tengas una columna de "Secuencia" o utilizar la Primary Key, (esa opción te lo dejo a tu criterio) ya que es la manera mas fácil de llevar el control de tus registros en las tablas al menos para el escenario que estas presentando. La columna secuencia ira incrementando con forme realices los insert en las tablas que nos comentas. bueno

**Va la practica, primero montemos el escenario:**

se crean 2 tablas PERSONA Y PERSONA_2

```
CREATE TABLE PERSONA
(
PE_NAME VARCHAR2(30),
PE_SEQUENCE INT 
)


CREATE TABLE PERSONA_2
(
PE_NAME VARCHAR2(30),
PE_SEQUENCE INT 
)
```

Se realizan los inserts a la tabla PERSONA y PERSONA_2

```
INSERT INTO PERSONA(PE_NAME,PE_SEQUENCE) VALUES ('RUBEN',1);
INSERT INTO PERSONA(PE_NAME,PE_SEQUENCE) VALUES ('URIEL',2);
INSERT INTO PERSONA(PE_NAME,PE_SEQUENCE) VALUES ('MANUEL',3);
INSERT INTO PERSONA(PE_NAME,PE_SEQUENCE) VALUES ('MOISES',4);
INSERT INTO PERSONA(PE_NAME,PE_SEQUENCE) VALUES ('ROBERTO',5);


INSERT INTO PERSONA_2(PE_NAME,PE_SEQUENCE) VALUES ('ROSA',1);
INSERT INTO PERSONA_2(PE_NAME,PE_SEQUENCE) VALUES ('ALOR',2);
INSERT INTO PERSONA_2(PE_NAME,PE_SEQUENCE) VALUES ('XUNI',3);
INSERT INTO PERSONA_2(PE_NAME,PE_SEQUENCE) VALUES ('MARIA',4);
INSERT INTO PERSONA_2(PE_NAME,PE_SEQUENCE) VALUES ('LUZ',5);
```

Finalmente el query para obtener al ultimo de cada tabla quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT * FROM 
 ---SE OBTIENE EL ULTIMO DE LA PRIMERA TABLA
 (SELECT * FROM PERSONA WHERE PE_SEQUENCE = (SELECT MAX(PE_SEQUENCE) FROM PERSONA)) P1,
 ---SE OBTIENE EL ULTIMO DE LA SEGUNDA TABLA
 (SELECT * FROM PERSONA_2 WHERE PE_SEQUENCE = (SELECT MAX(PE_SEQUENCE) FROM PERSONA_2)) P2
 --SE COMPARA ENTRE LOS DOS ULTIMOS OBTENIDOS SI CUMPLEN CON LA CONDICIÓN
 WHERE P1.PE_NAME = P2.PE_NAME
;
```

La magia esta en obtener el número mayor de secuencia ("el ultimo")  para indicar en el **WHERE** del **SELECT** que se hace a **PERSONA** Y **PERSONA_2** que filtre por ese número, eso se realiza justo aquí (Nota que se hace una subconsulta para a la tabla persona con la función MAX para recuperar dicho valor):

```
WHERE PE_SEQUENCE = (SELECT MAX(PE_SEQUENCE) FROM PERSONA)
```

*Esa lógica de filtrado aplica para ambas tablas.*

Finalmente la condición que tu nos muestras la puedes realizar después de la declaración de la segunda tabla.

```
 --TU CONDICION DE COMPARACIÓN ENTRE LAS COLUMNAS DE LAS DOS TABLAS
     WHERE P1.PE_NAME = P2.PE_NAME
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias por ensenarme tan limpio y claro exitos Katz

Comment: De nada viejo saludos cordiales.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.colum1 from   tabla1 as A, tabla2 as B where A.campo1= B.campo2 ORDER BY [columna_con_primary_key] DESC LIMIT 1
```

Esto sacaría lo mismo, pero limitandolo a un solo registro y por ultimo registro de la tabla es muy relativo, según el campo por el que ordenes el ultimo registro de la tabla varía, pero entiendo por ultimo registro el que te da la ordenación por defecto de la primaria, esto podría valerte.